# Can I make mirroring application without rooting?

Tags: android, casting, chromecast, mirroring, presentation

I want make **mirroring android application.(Sender)**

I wrote question about "mirroring" yesterday and..
I got "**Presentation APIs**" -API 17-.
(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html)

But, I still don`t know **how can I access screen video stream.**

Therefore, My question is this.

1. **How can I make packet that phone`s screen stream?(both video & audio)**
2. **Is ADT provide APIs about mirroring?**
3. **Is it need root privileges?**

I found mirroring APIs for only SAMSUNG Galaxy phones. 
But I finding android common API.

Please help me..
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Chromecast App allows screen mirroring - at least for certain devices like Nexus 5, 7, 10 ... So I don't think it would make much sense for you to pursue that.

Comment: I know :) So I trying this.
I want make application like Chromecast`s mirroring function.